# Cloning Record, mapping the Id coming up as null

Tags: apex

I am trying to clone a child record (master detail relationship) when a certain record type of opportunity creates. However my map is not working and I get the error:

> REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Related
>   Opportunity]

I have tried to change the trigger point to update but get the same error so I am doing something wrong with my Map but not sure what.

Trigger:

```
 if(Trigger.isAfter){  
    if(Trigger.isInsert){                

            for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
                if(opp.RecordTypeId == rtReview.getRecordTypeId()){
                    createbrief.add(opp);
                  }

            }
            if(createbrief != null && createbrief.size() > 0){
                OpportunityUtil.CreateReviewBrief(createbrief);
            }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public static void CreateReviewBrief(Opportunity[] opps){
    List<Review_Brief__c> newBriefList = new List<Review_Brief__c>();
    List<Review_Brief__c> oldBriefList = new List<Review_Brief__c>();
    List<Opportunity> oldBriefOppList = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, List<Opportunity>> accIds = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>{};
    Set<String> oldbriefId = new Set<String>();
    for(Opportunity opp: [select Id, Account.Regarding_Review_Brief__c, Account.Regarding_Review_Brief__r.Id from Opportunity where Id in : opps]){
        //initial review
        if(opp.Account.Regarding_Review_Brief__c == null){
            Review_Brief__c newBrief = new Review_Brief__c();
            newBrief.Related_Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
            newBrief.Name = 'Name will auto update';
            newBriefList.add(newBrief);
        }
        //not the first review, clone the latest one
        else if(opp.Account.Regarding_Review_Brief__c != null){
            oldbriefId.add(opp.Account.Regarding_Review_Brief__r.Id);
            oldBriefOppList.add(opp);
        }

    }
    oldBriefList = [Select Id, Name, Related_Opportunity__r.Id from Review_Brief__c where Id in: oldBriefId];
    Map<Id, Id> m = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < oldBriefOppList.size(); i++) {
        m.put(oldBriefOppList[i].Id, oldBriefList[i].Related_Opportunity__r.Id);
    }
    for(Review_Brief__c rbrief : oldBriefList){
        Review_Brief__c newBrief = rbrief.clone();        
        newBrief.Related_Opportunity__c = m.get(newBrief.Related_Opportunity__c);
        newBrief.Status__c = 'In Progress';
        newBriefList.add(newBrief);
    }
    if(newBriefList != null && newBriefList.size() > 0){
        insert newBriefList;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
newBrief.Related_Opportunity__c = m.get(newBrief.Related_Opportunity__c);
```

Attempts to get the map value for the `newBrief.Related_Opportunity__c`

But it should be

```
newBrief.Related_Opportunity__c = m.get(rBrief.Related_Opportunity__c);
```

As the map is populated with the **old** brief opp ids

Your code is unnecessarily complex and could use some revisions.

Code could be reduced to this, give it a try and see:

```
public static void CreateReviewBrief(Opportunity[] opps){

    Map<Id,Review_Brief__c> briefMap = new Map<Id,Review_Brief__c>();
    Review_Brief__c[] briefDMLList = New Review_Brief__c[]{};

    for(Opportunity opp: [select Id, AccountID, Account.Regarding_Review_Brief__c, Account.Regarding_Review_Brief__r.name, Account.Regarding_Review_Brief__r.Id from Opportunity where Id in : opps]){
            //Create a Map of all New brief records related to the opportunity by Account Id to prevent duplicates
            //You will need to figure out how to handle multiple opps from same account creating briefs
            briefMap.put(
                opp.AccountId,
                new Review_Brief__c(
                    Related_Opportunity__c = opp.id,
                    Id = opp.Account.Regarding_Review_Brief__c //if not null we know it is not the initial
                    Name = opp.Account.Regarding_Review_brief__r.Name
                )
            );

        }

    }

    //Cycle through the Brief records and for those that do have an ID, create the clone and add it to the DML list, no Id, set the Name and add to list
    for(Review_Brief__c b : briefMap.values()){     
            Review_Brief__c tmp = b.id == null ? b : b.clone(false, true);

            if(tmp.Id != null){
                //This is not the initial brief - Not sure why you are creating a new one instead of updating the existing but this does what your initial code does so...
                tmp.Status__c = 'In Progress';
            }else{
              tmp.Name = 'Name will autoupdate';
              //You did not have a status set for the initial Brief in your code so nothing was set here
            }

            briefDMLList.add(tmp);
        }
    }

    insert briefDMLList;

}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I am trying to clone the last brief and put the related_opportunity__c as the opportunity just inserted.

Comment: Changing to newBrief.Related_Opportunity__c = m.get(newBrief.Id); did not fix the issue. I also originally had the query of Related_Opportunity__c instead of Related_Opportunity__r.Id but I had the same issue. If my code is too complex can you provide details on how I can clone the record and update Related_Opportunity__c to the value of the newly inserted Opportunity?

Comment: @Michael See updated answer. Go from there. The first part of my answer is valid and you may have problems elsewhere. Suggest you start will the code I posted and report back. Basic debugging MAY be required

Comment: @Michael - Modification made to code for duplicate Brief/Account handling. I also misread your code and am removing that part of my answer

Comment: I had a go but get the following error: Loop must iterate over a collection type: Map on line 22 of your code

Comment: @Michael - I said BASIC debugging required. Fixed it for ya though

Comment: @Michael - Should be final modification. What status are you setting the New Brief record to (The initial ones)

Comment: @Michael - Ok, final final is done. Let us know if there are any issues

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, just did some testing and it is working correctly. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Eric sorry I was testing blank data(other than lookup Ids) but forgot to test that actual purpose of the cloning which is to carry across all field values. This doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: @Michael - You need to query for the fields you want to clone. In your original question you only queried for `Id, Name, Related_Opportunity__r.Id` so that is what I did. You will have to gather all the Ids for the Records to clone, query for the values, clone, then put in the list. Cloning a record does not magically get all existing field data. If the list of fields is minimal, you can add it to the Opportunity query in the beginning and populate it there

Comment: Ah ok, if that is the case I may as well use the process builder for this. I cant think of any other reason not to? My hope was that clone would allow me to add fields later if needed without having to come back and change code/workflows.

Comment: @Michael - Not sure what you mean. You can make it so new fields are added automatically http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2011/03/28/cloning-records-in-apex/. PB would (currently) be my last resort for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48640/discussion-between-michael-and-eric).